# Ищу информацию по архитектуре игр серии Worms

Tags: c++, ооп, ecs

Меня интересует, как внутри организованы игры серии `Worms`.

Для упрощения, я рассматриваю `Worms World Party` и `Worms Armageddon`. Найти сакральные коды, чтобы хотя бы одним глазком посмотреть на них, мне не удалось.

Опытным путем я разобрался с тем, как реализована механика коллизий и взрывов, навигация червя по растровому ландшафту и даже планирование действий AI системой. Но есть и то, над чем я очень плотно думаю уже довольно долго.

А именно: как объекты взаимодействуют между собой?

Ведь типов объектов довольно много, они разные, но в тоже время и очень похожи. Например, на все действует баллистика (кроме пуль). Черви, гранаты, мины - ведут себя одинаково при воздействии на них импульса. В то же время, мины взрываются при контакте с червями, и только при контакте с ними. Ящики при контакте с червями что-то им дают, и так далее.

Все эти взаимодействия происходят постоянно.

Я попытался построить такое взаимодействие при помощи паттерна `Entity-Component-System`, хотя и сильно сомневаюсь, что в 2001 году такое использовали. Даже элементарная система баллистики превратилась в лапшу, которую не получается упростить. Постоянно возникают неудобные моменты при попытке разделить сущности на компоненты, а системы на подсистемы.

В теории это конечно хорошо, когда объект представлен набором компонентов, которыми можно управлять прямо в рантайме. Проблема в том, что при использовании `ECS` (вместо `ООП`) зависимости и логика никуда не исчезают, а только размалываются на более мелкие части, которые расплываются во все стороны и перепутываются.

Безусловно, если `ECS` уже реализована, то это очень удобно для дизайнера, который может взять компоненты `A`, `B` и `C`, и сделать собираемый ящик, гранату с запалом или взрывающуюся бочку с напалмом. Но программировать это невероятно тяжело, потому что приходится мыслить совсем другими категориями.

Затем я попытался построить взаимодействие между объектами при помощи различных `ООП` подходов. Проблемы тоже были.

В общем, я очень хочу понять, как все это делается правильно.

Comment: там на лапше можно все сделать, не такая уж сложная игра.

Comment: https://github.com/CiaranMcCann/Worms-Armageddon-HTML5-Clone

Comment: Полезные ресурсы [раз](https://worms2d.info/Worms_Armageddon), [два](https://worms2d.info/4).